# How to check if a mouse is in many (120) different regions in HTML5 canvas efficiently?

Tags: javascript, canvas, onclick, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I have a polar graph (see image) with 120 different points. I want to make it so if the user clicks or hovers on one of the points, the coordinate of that point is displayed. I have an array called `pointCoordinates` that stores each canvas coordinate of each points like this:

```
[[x1, y1], [x2, y2] ... [x120, y120]]
```

This is how I am capturing mouse coordinates (which I might later change to click):

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
}
```

I was originally planning to use a formula to check if the mouse is in a certain region (using the distance formula) or simplifying it all into a circle. Either way, this will require me to have 120 different if statements to check for this. I feel like this is inefficient and probably slow. Are there other methods for doing this?

[image: Polar Graph with Points]

Edit:

To provide more information, these points will NOT be draggable. I am planning to display something like a tooltip near the point that was clicked where the polar coordinates of the point will be shown.

Edit 2:

After using the code posted below and drawing a rectangle in the "clickable" spot  on the map, I get this image. I do not want the click detection to be perfect, but this is pretty far off after pi/3. Any ideas how to fix this? I used this code to generate the black spots:

```
for(var x = 0; x < WIDTH*2/3; x++){
        for(var y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++){
          var mp = realToPolar(x, y);//converts canvas x and y into polar
          if(checkRadialDistance(mp[0], mp[1])){ //returns true if in bounds
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
          }
        }
      }
```

Playing around with the constants still generates the same pattern, just of different thicknesses. `checkRadialDistance` is just the renamed `checkr` function that inside calls `checkrt`.
[image]

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/hofemozira/edit?html,output) Keep in mind, width of screen has to be greater than height for this to work properly.

The image generated by `mt-rt`. I later made a minor edit, so that whole circle is covered when theta = 0.

[image]

Comment: 120 is not that much, but yes, there may be several different and probably better approaches than checking every point, but it will highly depend on your application: What will happen after? Will these points be e.g draggable? Could they have a non uniform distribution? All in all, your question as it stands right now is too broad to give a correct answer.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you for your response. I have made an edit to answer your questions.

Comment: Right on your del. And you can "break;" after displaying coordinates. Thanks.

Comment: I did not check your JSBIN -- I did not notice it :( It would take some time for me to work with it. Your last image looks quite reasonable, but the JSBIN doesn't give that. The del/r comes from arc distance = (mrmt-prpt)<del. If you're looking at how t can vary when mr=pr=r, then abs(r(mt-pt))<del or abs(mt-pt)<del/r. The range of mt is pt-del/r to pt+del/r. Whatever you are doing to get your last image, the longer "rectangles" at the higher r's would be reduced if you used del/r instead of del.

Comment: I did what you did -- have the mouse go over the whole canvas and darken the "close" pixels and the results are similar to your middle image. Something is wrong with my algorithm.  Sorry.  Your last image looks good.

Comment: I redid my answer. I owe you some points. Your last image looks pretty good. Thanks for the fun.

Comment: @dcromley makes sense now! Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: @Nick Solonko  (I don't know if my making and EDIT sends you a notification). I didn't like using atan -- here are some speed improvements.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: My (accepted) answer was bad. This corrects it:

This assumes r to be 1 to 5. Convert mouse cartesian mx,my to polar mr,mt. First check if mr is close to 1 of the 5 radii. Function checkr does that. If it is close, then check if mt is close to 1 of the 24 thetas. Function checkt does that. A complication is that the atan2 function is not continuous at pi radians which is where points are at, so make the discontinuity at -pi/24 radians where there are no points.

A "close" value is pi/24 since the arc distance between two adjacent points at r=1 will be pi/12.

```
var del = 1*Math.PI/24*.7; // for example

function xy2rt(xy) { // to polar cordinates
  var rt = [];
  rt.push(Math.sqrt(xy[0]*xy[0]+xy[1]*xy[1])); // r
  var zatan = Math.atan2(xy[1], xy[0]);
  // make the discontinuity at -pi/24
  if (zatan < -Math.PI/24) zatan += 2*Math.PI; 
  rt.push(zatan); // theta
  return rt;
}
function checkr() { // check radial distance
  for (var pr=1; pr<=5; pr+=1) { // 5 radii
    if (Math.abs(mr-pr) < del) { checkt(pr); break; }
  }
}  
function checkt(pr) { // check theta
  var pt;
  for (var ipt=0; ipt<24; ipt+=1) { // 24 thetas
    pt = ipt / 24 * 2 * Math.PI; 
    if (Math.abs(mt-pt) < del/pr) { 
      // is close -- do whatever
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

My problem was when checking the arc distance, I was using mr and pr whereas only pr should be used. The OP found my error by processing every pixel on the canvas and found there was a problem. I also processed every pixel and this image shows the routines to be correct now. The black is where the routines determine that the pixel is close to one of the 120 points.
[image]

EDIT: Faster processing
There are a lot of Math.* functions being executed. Although I haven't timed anything, I think this has to be much faster.
1) The x,y coordintates of the 120 points are stored in arrays.
2) Instead of getting polar mr, mt, pr, and pt, use vector processing.

Here is the derivation of arcd, the arc distance using vectors.

```
sint = sin(theta) = (M cross P)/mr/pr (cross product Mouse X Point)  
cost = cos(theta) = (M dot P)/mr/pr (dot product Mouse . Point)  
sint will be used to get arc distance, but sint goes to zero at theta=+-pi as well as theta=0, so:
mdotp will be used to determine if theta is near zero and not +-pi
arcd = pr*theta
arcd = pr*sin(theta) (good approximation for small theta)  
arcd = pr*abs(M cross P)/mr/mp (from above)
if ardd < del, check if mdotp > 0.
```

Here are the load-xy-arrays and the new checkr and checkt routines.

```
  apx=[], apy=[]; // the saved x,y of the 120 points 
function loadapxapy() { // load arrays of px, py
  var itheta, theta
  for (var pr=1; pr<=5; pr+=1) { // 2-dimension arrays
    apx[pr] = []; apy[pr] = []; // 5 arrays, 1 for each pr
    for (itheta=0; itheta<24; itheta+=1) { // 24 x's and y's
      theta = Math.PI*itheta/12; 
      apx[pr][itheta] = pr*Math.cos(theta); 
      apy[pr][itheta] = pr*Math.sin(theta);
    }
  }
}
function checkr() { // check radial distance
  var mr = Math.sqrt(mx*mx+my*my); // mouse r
  for (var pr=1; pr<=5; pr+=1) { // check 1 to 5
   if (Math.abs(mr-pr) < del) { // mouser - pointr
      checkt(mr, pr); // if close, check thetas
    }
  }
}  
function checkt(mr, pr) { // check thetas
  var px, py, sint, mdotp, arcd;
  for (var itheta=0; itheta<24; itheta+=1) { // check 24
    px = apx[pr][itheta]; // get saved x
    py = apy[pr][itheta]; // and y
    // This arcd is derived from vector processing 
    // At least this doesn't use the accursed "atan"!
    sint = Math.abs(mx*py-my*px)/mr/pr; // sine
    arcd = pr*sint; // arc distance
    if (arcd<del) { // arc distance check
      mdotp = (mx*px+my*py); // final check
      if (mdotp > 0) { // to see if theta is near zero and not +-pi
        setpixelxy([mx, my]); // or whatever..
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - I think I get the principle. I think that the arc distance is pi/12 (abs(1*0 - pi/12*1)) between each adjacent point for r=1. Therefore, I can make del=pi/24.

Comment: I got it working after changing the second function to check if mt-pt < del.

Comment: @Nick Solonko  You were right that del = pi/24 (.131). But (IMHO) I don't see how "mt-pt<del" can be right. For the point (1,0)[polar(1,0)] and a mouse point (1.000,0.140)polar[(1.010,.139)], the test 0.140-0<.131 fails like it should. But for the point (2,0)[polar(2,0)] and a mouse point (2.000,0.140)[polar(2.005,.070)], the test 0.070-0<.131 PASSES, BUT IT SHOULD FAIL. By comparing mrmt-prpt<del, that would be 2.005*0.070-0*0<.131 or 0.140>.131 which fails, like it should.  ?

Comment: did you check the attached JS bin? Also, check my edit with the generated image for mt-pt.

Comment: Also, how did you get `del/r`?

Comment: Thanks for the update! The original approach takes almost exactly 100ms to execute, which I am fine with. Maybe some others will benefit from your speed up, but I prefer the original because it is more concise.